# I2C Read and I2C Write behaviour with registers and no answer from device

Tags: c, embedded, i2c

I've read quite some detailed tutorials and guides about i2c but what it's not clear to me is the following:

Assume you have to read a register on a i2c slave device,

do i need to "write" on the i2c the first 7 bits as slave_address, 1 bit with R/W and then the reg_address (as data) and then issue a "read" to listen for the bytes

```
h_i2c *i2c_dev = i2c_drv_open(I2C1_PORT, SLAVE_ADDRESS);
write_data[0] = 0x21;
write_len = i2c_drv_write(i2c_h, write_data, 1);
if (write_len != 1)
    printf("error write_len is %d", write_len);

uint8_t read_data[5];
read_len = i2c_drv_read(i2c_h, read_data, 5);
if (read_len != 5)
    wmprintf("error read_len is %d", read_len);
```

or

do i need to issue only a read to an address which is the "combination" of the slave and the register i want to read?

Moreover the "auto-incremental" property means that as long as i give SDA control over to the slave he will keep sending data?

EDIT1:

quoting the pdf:

The ENS210 is an I²C slave device with a fixed slave address of
0x43. This means that the first byte after a start condition is
1000 011x, where x indicates the data direction, so 0x86 (1000
0110) for write and 0x87 (1000 0111) for read.

Here is the output

https://imgur.com/a/8G8UR

On the rising edge i see 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1

The last one means nACK.

My ideas are:

1. Sensor is dead
2. Resistance is bad, sensor can't pull down the SDA line
3. Frequency is at 125khz is it normal?

PS:
SCL probe had issue so signal quality is better from what you see here

Regards,

Comment: The data sheet for the device you're trying to talk to should show full transaction waveform diagrams, that make this clear. I'd say it's the former.

Comment: All the I2C peripheras I've seen work as your example, with a write operation and then a write operation, and if you read 5 bytes you read address 0x21 to 0x25.

Comment: @JMA updated first post

Comment: @unwind updated first post

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the I2C device.  Most I've seen make you set the address pointer first with a write, then perform a read:

[START]->[ADDR(W)]->[REG]->[RESTART]->[ADDR(R)]->[DATABYTES]->[STOP]

Most devices I've seen will begin reading data from the register specified and auto-increment the address pointer for each data byte ACKed by the master.  Each data byte read will be sequential in memory.  This is not always the case however.  Many devices will actually let you turn register auto-increment off if desired.

Some devices I've seen work a little different with how they expect read register commands to come in.  Some devices don't let you set the register to read AT ALL and you have to do a sequential read to get at the data you want.  An I2C device should have this information of how it is expecting reads/write commands in the datasheet complete with waveform diagrams.

Comment: ENS210 is the i2c device i'm looking at